# sed /awk/grep to delete every thing except matching pattern in a text file

Tags: sed, awk, command, terminal, grep

hi i have a file let pattern.txt

contains

pattern1

pattern2

pattern3

pattern4

another text file let(complex.txt)

contains lines as

path:  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(XXXXXXXXX,'pattern1/2/3/4')XXXXXXXXXXXX

path:  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(XXXXXXXXX,'pattern1/2/3/4')XXXXXXXXXXXX

path:  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(XXXXXXXXX,'pattern1/2/3/4')XXXXXXXXXX

now the prob is :::i have to get another file filter.txt by matching pattern.txt to complex.txt  which will contain a line as

path:pattern1/2/3/4.....

i tried...but i am not getting....

can someone help....thanks in adv...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which type of regex (Basic, extended, perl?) does pattern.txt contain?

If extended, just use awk:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
        patterns[$0]++; 
        next;
    } 
    {
        for (el in patterns) 
            if (match($0,el)) {
                print $1 substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
                next;
            } 
    }' pattern.txt complex.txt >filter.txt
```

The above code relies on the space between "path:" and the rest of the line in complex.txt.